# Terminal command line quick navigation

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I would like to move between the command line arguments in a fast way. For example, if I have the following command line:

```
> do_something_with /very_long_path/to_a_very_long_directory/ more_args
                    ^                                       ^
```

I would like to skip the whole path (jump between the ^ symbols). I'm already familiar with word mode (Alt+B and Alt+F) but in some scenarios it's not enough to navigate quickly between the arguments.

Comment: may fit better on superuser

Comment: Please, feel free to move the question there if you have permissions. Thanks.

Comment: For information, in my terminal (gnome-terminal) there is an option to select word delimiter, which works well to configure the double click behaviour.
Unfortunately, it works only with the mouse so, I guess that there's a way to find an equivalent for the bash readline.

Comment: thanks, but I'm trying to avoid mouse usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (quote from [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Commands-For-Moving))

> ```
> shell-forward-word ()
> ```
>
> Move forward to the end of the next word. Words are delimited by non-quoted shell metacharacters.

and

> ```
> shell-backward-word ()
> ```
>
> Move back to the start of the current or previous word. Words are delimited by non-quoted shell metacharacters.

I have bound them to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> by adding this to my `.inputrc`:

```
"\e\C-f": shell-forward-word
"\e\C-b": shell-backward-word
```

Answer (score 2):

In bash, you can set the cursor to the previous given character using the following features:

`character-search` and `character-search-backward` features.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>, (resp. <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>) + `searched_character`

In your example, you can search backward for a space.

```
> do_something_with /very/long/path/\ with_spaces\ directory/ more_args
                 ^                                        ^
```

Unfortunately, this will not work so well with paths like:

```
> do_something_with /very_\ long_path/to_a_\ very_long_directory/ more_args
```

As a sidenote, you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> to go at the beginning / end of a line.

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't answer my question. Any way +1 for the searching functionality. Very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

For vi/vim users `ctrl+] + char` can  be used to quickly navigate to the first occurance of a given char. Which is equivalent to `f + char` in vi/vim.